# How to send body to express app with fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I am trying to post a form using javascript to an express API endpoint

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import logger from 'morgan';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import validator from 'express-validator';
import cors from 'cors';

import indexRouter from './routes/index';

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/', indexRouter);

export default app;
```

Here is my form event handler

```
signin_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.getElementById('signin_email').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('signin_password').value;
    console.log('SIGN IN', email, password);

    const body = { email, password };
    console.log(body);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body,
        headers: { 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
    };
    fetch(signinEndpoint, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(resp => {
            console.log('response ', resp);
        });
});
```

When I submit the form directly with the action method, everything works fine. But when I try to handle the submit event by myself, the sent email and password always return undefined.

I have tried almost every suggestion here on SO. I've used `FormData()`. When I log `req.body` on my console I get

```
   '"email"\r\n\r\nperson@gmail.com\r\n-----------------------------3902153292\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="password"\r\n\r\ngaatatra\r\n-----------------------------3902153292--\r\n' }
```

If I try to use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, the browser throws up `cors` complaints.

If I use `JSON.stringify(body)`, console.log returns `{ '{"email":"person@gmail.com","password":"taeatertrt"}': '' }`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` instead? don't forget to use `body: JSON.stringify(body)` before send your data

Comment: I tried that. But with `application/json` the browser complains of `cors`.

Comment: That means that you need to add the cors npm module, you can use app.use(cors("*")), for a quick fix but that's not a best practice. check the module docs and add a proper config

Comment: you need to add at least "*" inside the brackets.

Comment: Sure. Adding the star worked. Now the form data is being read. Thanks and accepted. I always thought cors was enabled the way it is.

Comment: Always check the documentation carefully before to use a module, this will save your time ;)